# creating a Google cloud bucket throws error

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-storage

My dilemma is not trying to create a Google cloud bucket, i can do that like so:

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({projectId: 'my-project', keyFilename: "key.json" });
async function createBucket() {
   await storage.createBucket('my-bucket');
};
createBucket().catch(console.error);
```

This works fine, but this is not how i'm going to call my function to create a bucket.
Here is my function in a file called cloudStorage.js to create the bucket:

```
 const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

 const storage = new Storage({ projectId: 'my-project', keyFilename: "key.json" });
 module.exports = {
  createGoogleBucket: async ({ bucketName }) => {
      await storage.createBucket(bucketName);
  },
};
```

When i call it like so:

```
  const  cloudStorage  = require('../src/cloudStorage');
  await cloudStorage.createGoogleBucket('my-bucket');
```

I get the following error:

```
   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: callback is not a function
  at C:\code\BigQueryDemo\node_modules\@google-cloud\storage\build\src\storage.js:312:17
```

Why is this error being thrown when I call my function to create a bucket and how do i fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this somewhat misleading error message because the google cloud library thinks you're trying to pass a callback instead of the bucket name. This is happening because in this code:

```
  createGoogleBucket: async ({ bucketName }) => {
      await storage.createBucket(bucketName);
  },
```

`({ bucketName })` is a [*destructuring assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) - it tries to assign a local variable `bucketName` by accessing the `bucketName` property of whatever the first argument that gets passed to the function is. In this case, you're passing a string literal - and string literals have no `bucketName` property. Therefore, you're actually passing `undefined` to `storage.createBucket()`. To fix, simply remove the brackets so you're not trying to destructure the string:

```
  createGoogleBucket: async (bucketName) => {
      await storage.createBucket(bucketName);
  },
```

Comment: You're incredible! I followed Google's instructions for creating buckets. I'll do more reading on destructing assignments as well. Thank you